# How to hide some of these pages in the menu on mobile navigation?

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to change the menu options to only "Home", "Jobs" and "Contact" on the mobile navigation.

Each menu item has a menu ID which I have tried to hide using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  li#menu-item-14209 { 
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And other similar media screen queries. The menu item disappears on desktop version, but never on the mobile version even when I don't specify a media query.

`li#menu-item-14209` is the CSS for the menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your mobile menu is different from desktop's and does not have the classes.
You can use `:nth-child` selector like this:

```
.slicknav_nav li:nth-child(X) {
display: none;
}
```

Where (X) is a number of an element from the mobile menu from top. 
And this is CSS to leave only "Home", "Jobs" and "Contact".

```
.slicknav_nav li:nth-child(2), .slicknav_nav li:nth-child(3), .slicknav_nav li:nth-child(5) {
display: none;
}
```